# Sharing port 80 between sharepoint and default IIS website

Tags: iis, sharepoint, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a sharepoint application on root of my webserver.
Is it possible to have sharepoint (2010) and IIS 7.5 share the same port (80)?

To be specific, the problem is with a web application I need to host on IIS default web web site. Isn't there a way to exclude some directory from sharepoint?

**Edit:** Apparently I asked a wrong question. The scenario I was working on was to put a ASP.Net application under a Sharepoint website. (eg sharepointserver/aspapp) It turned out that I should not expect my files to be served from inetpub\wwwroot. since sharepoint has created another site on port 80 inetpub\wwwroot\wss I had to put my files there. It's fixed now, but the new problem irrelevant to the previous one is hosting a Asp.Net 4 application under a Asp.Net 2 application (sharepoint 2010). Apparently web configs get mixed up and produce some problem. At the end I've given up and hosted my Asp.Net 4 app on another port! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharepoint is a technology that is served through IIS. In other words, IIS can run sharepoint and other websites side by side, through the same IP address and the same port. The various sites are distinguished by their virtual host entries (these are the URLs you have to type into your web browser).

You only need multiple IP addresses if you want to server multiple HTTPS sites through the same server (each site then also needs a certificate).

Read up on IIS configuration, this is a standard case.

Comment: This seems to be the answer, but take a look at this page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899711/en-us 
There has to be an exclude option in sharepoint, but I'm not finding it in sharepoint 2010.

Comment: @Mohammad: It's in the Central administration, called "[Define managed paths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288905%28v=office.14%29.aspx)".

Answer (score 0):

You can add another ip address to the server and bind it to the default web site, which will allow you to run your web site and Sharepoint both on port 80, on different ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

My company routinely runs several wep applications side by side on a single port.

Setup each IIS site to listen to a seperate URL. (It's handled in the Binding property)
Thus, the same physical box serves www.myaspsite.com and www.mysharepointsite.com at the same time, on the same port (80). Any user browsing to www.myaspsite.com will see the IIS / Asp site already there. Anyone going to mysharepoint... sees the sharepoint site.

It's also possible to stack your prefixes on different IIS sites on the same machine, using the same port. For instance, have an IIS / ASP.net site setup for www.mycompany.com and a separate SharePoint site responding to wss.mycompany.com

If your computer has seperate NICs (one for internet and one for intranet, for example) you can limit an IIS / ASP site to respond only to the internet side, and have the SharePoint site respond only to the intranet side. But this is generally confising to end-users and not recommended.